# List number of columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to list the number of columns in a MySQL database table with PHP. How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I can't see why this post got upvoted just now (edit, which was retracted). Honestly, some effort on their part is required and a simple Google search will reveal many results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` built into every MySQL server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) can be used to find this information.

Try this query to get a list of each table in your current database along with its number of columns.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) AS column_count
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
 GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
```

If you want just one table's results, try something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS column_count
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='mytable'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count number of columns then use

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE table_schema = 'database_name'
         AND table_name = 'tbl_name';
```

Comment: And also need to list rows